# Is my understanding of limit points wrong?

Tags: general-topology

From Munkres p. 163:

"The notion of compactness is not nearly so natural as that of connectedness. From the beginnings of topology, it was clear that the closed interval $[a, b]$ of the real line had a certain property that was crucial for proving such theorems as the maximum value theorem and the uniform continuity theorem. But for a long time, it was not clear how this property should be formulated for an arbitrary topological space. **It used to be thought that the crucial property of $[a, b]$ was the fact that every infinite subset of $[a, b]$ has a limit point**."

Isn't that true for $(a,b)$ also? Isn't $a$ a limit point of $(a,b)$?

Comment: But $a \notin (a,b)$. Considering $(a,b)$ as a topological space, $a$ does not exist.

Comment: So $a$ exists only when we consider $(a,b)$ as a subspace of $\Bbb{R}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The boldface sentence should be understood as follows:

> It used to be thought that the crucial property of $[a,b]$ was the fact that every infinite subset of $[a,b]$ has a limit point in $[a,b]$.

Yes, $a$ is a limit point of $(a,b)$ **in the space** $\Bbb R$, but the set $\left\{a+\frac{b-a}n:n\ge 2\right\}$ is a subset of $(a,b)$ with no limit point in $(a,b)$. That difference turns out to be crucial.